# Webcam not working on HP Truvision HD

Tags: 18.04, hp, webcam, cheese

I am using an [HP 15-ac650tu](https://support.hp.com/nz-en/document/c04997085).
Any app/google meet says **can't detect any webcam** .
Here is the error on calling `cheese` or `sudo cheese`. Both of the commands throw the same error on the terminal and the window goes all black.

```
(cheese:5569): Gtk-WARNING **: 08:55:07.899: Theme parsing error: cheese.css:7:35: The style property GtkScrollbar:min-slider-length is deprecated and shouldn't be used anymore. It will be removed in a future version

** (cheese:5569): CRITICAL **: 08:55:11.980: cheese_preferences_dialog_on_source_change: assertion '_tmp2_ > ((guint) 0)' failed

(cheese:5569): cheese-CRITICAL **: 08:55:11.980: cheese_camera_device_get_name: assertion 'CHEESE_IS_CAMERA_DEVICE (device)' failed

(cheese:5569): GLib-CRITICAL **: 08:55:11.980: g_variant_new_string: assertion 'string != NULL' failed

(cheese:5569): GLib-CRITICAL **: 08:55:11.980: g_variant_ref_sink: assertion 'value != NULL' failed

(cheese:5569): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: 08:55:11.980: g_settings_schema_key_type_check: assertion 'value != NULL' failed

(cheese:5569): GLib-CRITICAL **: 08:55:11.981: g_variant_get_type_string: assertion 'value != NULL' failed

(cheese:5569): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: 08:55:11.981: g_settings_set_value: key 'camera' in 'org.gnome.Cheese' expects type 's', but a GVariant of type '(null)' was given

(cheese:5569): GLib-CRITICAL **: 08:55:11.981: g_variant_unref: assertion 'value != NULL' failed

** (cheese:5569): CRITICAL **: 08:55:11.981: cheese_preferences_dialog_setup_resolutions_for_device: assertion 'device != NULL' failed

** (cheese:5569): CRITICAL **: 08:55:13.697: cheese_preferences_dialog_on_source_change: assertion '_tmp2_ > ((guint) 0)' failed

(cheese:5569): cheese-CRITICAL **: 08:55:13.698: cheese_camera_device_get_name: assertion 'CHEESE_IS_CAMERA_DEVICE (device)' failed

(cheese:5569): GLib-CRITICAL **: 08:55:13.698: g_variant_new_string: assertion 'string != NULL' failed

(cheese:5569): GLib-CRITICAL **: 08:55:13.698: g_variant_ref_sink: assertion 'value != NULL' failed

(cheese:5569): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: 08:55:13.698: g_settings_schema_key_type_check: assertion 'value != NULL' failed

(cheese:5569): GLib-CRITICAL **: 08:55:13.698: g_variant_get_type_string: assertion 'value != NULL' failed

(cheese:5569): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: 08:55:13.698: g_settings_set_value: key 'camera' in 'org.gnome.Cheese' expects type 's', but a GVariant of type '(null)' was given

(cheese:5569): GLib-CRITICAL **: 08:55:13.698: g_variant_unref: assertion 'value != NULL' failed

** (cheese:5569): CRITICAL **: 08:55:13.698: cheese_preferences_dialog_setup_resolutions_for_device: assertion 'device != NULL' failed

(cheese:5569): cheese-WARNING **: 08:55:13.752: Could not read from resource.: gstv4l2bufferpool.c(1040): gst_v4l2_buffer_pool_poll (): /GstCameraBin:camerabin/GstWrapperCameraBinSrc:camera_source/GstBin:bin19/GstV4l2Src:v4l2src2:
poll error 1: Invalid argument (22)
```

Now I have seen some similar questions on the platform but no real solution.
I am on Ubuntu 18.04.5 and here are some more info.

```
$ hwinfo --usb
08: USB 00.0: 0000 Unclassified device
  [Created at usb.122]
  Unique ID: +rmv.PHDpAsyWur2
  Parent ID: pBe4.2DFUsyrieMD
  SysFS ID: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-5/2-5:1.0
  SysFS BusID: 2-5:1.0
  Hardware Class: unknown
  Model: "Chicony Electronics HP Truevision HD"
  Hotplug: USB
  Vendor: usb 0x04f2 "Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd"
  Device: usb 0xb50a "HP Truevision HD"
  Revision: "19.17"
  Serial ID: "200901010001"
  Driver: "uvcvideo"
  Driver Modules: "uvcvideo"
  Device File: /dev/input/event11
  Device Files: /dev/input/event11, /dev/input/by-id/usb-Generic_HP_Truevision_HD_200901010001-event-if00, /dev/input/by-path/pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:5:1.0-event
  Device Number: char 13:75
  Speed: 480 Mbps
  Module Alias: "usb:v04F2pB50Ad1917dcEFdsc02dp01ic0Eisc01ip00in00"
  Driver Info #0:
    Driver Status: uvcvideo is active
    Driver Activation Cmd: "modprobe uvcvideo"
  Config Status: cfg=new, avail=yes, need=no, active=unknown
  Attached to: #16 (Hub)
```

```
$ ls -ltr /dev/video*
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81, 0 Apr 21 16:02 /dev/video0
```

```
$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 04f2:b50a Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 0bda:b006 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 007: ID 0b0e:0305 GN Netcom 
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 413c:2107 Dell Computer Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 413c:301a Dell Computer Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

```
$ v4l2-ctl --list-devices
HP Truevision HD: HP Truevision (usb-0000:00:14.0-5):
    /dev/video0
```

Appreciate it if someone can throw some light on this issue.

Comment: In the output of `ls -ltr /dev/video*`, did you copy an incomplete line (missing `/dev/video0`), or is it correct?
In the first case, what you copied is very strange.

Comment: yeah, I guess I missed that. updated now. I have awarded the bounty for your efforts. Yet to find a solution though. Having a hard time with interviews.

Comment: Ok, good luck. If I find anything useful, I will post back.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**:
As per [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cheese/+bug/1758994), it may be a bug.
Try accessing the webcam with [camorama](https://github.com/alessio/camorama) or gstreamer, and check if that works.
If so, you are probably experiencing this bug.

**Related**:

1. https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/usb3-camera-error/83867
2. 

---

**Suggestions** to try solving the problem:

1. Use `sudo` when calling `cheese` ([ref](https://askubuntu.com/a/1245950/226614)).

**Suggestions** to increase your chances of getting help and the problem solved, if the solution proposed doesn't work:

1. Post exactly what you mean by "when trying to start".
2. Post the output of the commands listed in [HP Truevision HD built-in webcam not working in ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1219205/hp-truevision-hd-built-in-webcam-not-working-in-ubuntu-18-04)
3. Whenever you post the output of a command, post the exact command that you used to produce it.
4. Focus on readability of your question. Edit and reorganize slightly if that improves readability.

Comment: I read about doing a `sudo` before cheese, in one of the posts. that didn't work for me.

Comment: Also thanks for the edit suggestion, I have tried to incorporate more things.

Comment: thanks for all the suggestions the device is not able to connect with the camera for any app be it zoom, google meet. I did try camorama, which also throws an error saying  `Could not connect to video device(/dev/video0) Please check connection`

As I mentioned sudo cheese doesn't work either.